# Error with curl

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, openssl

I'm having this error with curl:

```
curl https://www.google.com -v
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:400e:c01::67...
* Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:400e:c01::67: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 74.125.28.103...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x4041f868e0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x4041f868e0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to www.google.com (74.125.28.103) port 443 (#0)
* error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* Closing connection 0
```

Ignore the network is unreachable... it happens with every https:// url, even if the network is reachable.

I won't install manually the certificates, cause it should get them automatically... ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Fix. I don't know what the problem was, but it was related to the certificates (ca-certificates) package.

It was fixed by adding `ca-certificates` and run `update-ca-certificates`

The distro I was using is Alpine LInux, so the commands are:

```
apk add ca-certificates
update-ca-certificates
```

In debian alike it should be:

```
apt-get install ca-certificates
update-ca-certificates
```